# How can I make consecutive waitForMessage wait for the consecutive messages?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To my surprise, the following simple program

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "std_msgs/Int32.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "test");

    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    std_msgs::Int32::ConstPtr ret;
    ret = ros::topic::waitForMessage<std_msgs::Int32>("/topic");
    ROS_INFO("%d", ret->data);
    ret = ros::topic::waitForMessage<std_msgs::Int32>("/topic");
    ROS_INFO("%d", ret->data);
    ret = ros::topic::waitForMessage<std_msgs::Int32>("/topic");
    ROS_INFO("%d", ret->data);

    ros::spin();

    return 0;
}
```

Prints 3 `0`s when I run a single `rostopic pub /topic std_msgs/Int32 "data: 0"`.

<s>One workaround is to add a `ros::Duration(1).sleep()` between the waits but that doesn't work for my situation.</s>

How can I have `waitForMessage` actually wait for 3 publishes, provided that I don't know the interval between publishes?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/368589/how-can-i-make-consecutive-waitformessage-wait-for-the-consecutive-messages?/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-12-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> To my surprise, the following simple program: [..] Prints 3 `0`s when I run a single `rostopic pub /topic std_msgs/Int32 "data: 0"`.

The behaviour you observe is actually as it should be, and the cause is not `waitForMessage(..)` doing something "wrong", but your expectations are incorrect.

The following is the output of the command you ran:

```
$ rostopic pub /topic std_msgs/Int32 "data: 0"
publishing and latching message. Press ctrl-C to terminate
```

Notice the "**and latching message**" part of what `rostopic pub` prints.

Latched publishers ([wiki/roscpp/Overview/Publishers and Subscribers - Publisher Options](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Publisher_Options)) will republish the last published message upon subscription by new subscribers, even if those subscribers were not online when the initial message was published.

So in your case, `rostopic pub` publishes "the 0" once when it is started, and then subsequently again for every `ros::Subscriber` created by `ros::topic::waitForMessage(..)` (as that function creates a new subsciber every time it is run).

Receiving the same message with every `waitForMessage(..)` seems to be as it should.

> One workaround is to add a `ros::Duration(1).sleep()` between the waits [..]

That would surprise me actually, as that's not how latched publishers work.

> How can I have `waitForMessage` actually wait for 3 publishes, provided that I don't know the interval between publishes?

I wouldn't know, as that's not what that function is for. How would it distinguish between "the same 0" and another message, which happens to also carry a 0?

As a final comment: please note that `waitForMessage(..)` is *not* intended to be used to periodically "sample" a message stream, or to implement some sort of rate-limiter (ie: calling `waitForMessage(..)` repeatedly in a `while` loop with a `ros::Rate` or something similar).

It is a fairly costly operation which is typically only used to get some initial state from a topic, or when really only a single message is needed for some reason.

In almost all other cases it would be better to use something like [message_filters](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters) and/or regular subscribers.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-12-30**:
Further testing shows the sleep workaround doesn't actually work.

**Comment by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on 2020-12-30**:
Curiously, it appears `waitForMessage` does not work as expected for non-latching messages, even if `waitForMessage` occurs before the publishing of the non-latching message, I've asked that as a [separate question](https://answers.ros.org/question/368646/why-does-waitformessage-not-work-for-non-latching-messages/)

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-12-30**:\

> Curiously, it appears `waitForMessage` does not work as expected for non-latching messages, even if `waitForMessage` occurs before the publishing of the non-latching message

`waitForMessage(..)` works fine for "non latched messages".

Perhaps you are expecting things to work in a way they don't.